# Use definition of Lebesgue integral for nonnegative functions to show $\int_{A}f=\int_{E}\chi_{A}f$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show the following:

> Let $f$ be a measurable function on a set $E$, and let $A$ be a measurable subset of $E$. Then, **using the definition of the Lebesgue Integral of nonnegative functions** (given below), prove that $\int_{A}f=\int_{E}\chi_{A}f$.
>
> **Definition of the Lebesgue Integral for Nonnegative Functions**: For an arbitrary nonnegative measurable function $f:E\to \mathbb{R} \cup + \infty$, define its Lebesgue integral by $\int_{E}f = \sup \left\{\int_{E} h \vert h\,\text{bounded, measurable, of finite support, and}\,0 \leq h \leq f\, \text{on}\,E \right\}$

Now, the definition holds only for nonnegative measurable functions. So, I let $f = f^{+}-f^{-}$ on $E$.  Then, we consider $\int_{E}\chi_{A}f = \int_{E}\chi_{A}f^{+}-\int_{E}\chi_{A}f^{-} $.

Applying the definition, we get that this is equal to $\sup\{\int_{E}h\vert h\,\text{bounded, measurable, of finite support, and}\,0 \leq h \leq \chi_{A}f^{+}\,\text{on}\,E\} -\sup\{\int_{E}h\vert \tilde{h}\,\text{bounded, measurable, of finite support, and}\,0 \leq \tilde{h} \leq \chi_{A}f^{+}\,\text{on}\,E\}$

where $h$ and $\tilde{h}$ are suitable nonnegative, bounded, measurable functions with finite support.

Since $A \subseteq E$, $h \leq \chi_{A}f^{+}$ and $\tilde{h} \leq \chi_{A}f^{-}$ on $A$ as well, and since $\chi_{A}$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$, $\chi_{A}f^{+}=\chi_{A}f^{-}=0$ on $E\backslash A$, so $h = \tilde{h}=0$ there as well.

Now, there is a corollary to the Monotone Convergence Theorem I would like to use in order to help me introduce series in a similar manner as in the second answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235481/restriction-of-a-lebesgue-integral-to-a-subset-of-a-measurable-set) (proving the same thing, but instead using the definition of the Lebesgue Integral for bounded functions).  The corollary states as follows:

> Let $\{ u_{n}\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions on $E$.  If $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}$ pointwise a.e. on $E$, then $\int_{E}f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{E}u_{n}$.

I'd somehow like to be able to express both $h$ and $\tilde{h}$ as a sum $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i}\chi_{\displaystyle [E_{i}\backslash A) \cup (E_{i}\cap A)]}$. But I am not sure I am 1) justified in doing it, 2) exactly how to do it.

Then, once I have that, I can apply the Corollary to turn the finite sum into an infinite series, and can use a bunch of bounding to get the result that I want. I just require assistance with this one part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems an unnecessary approach here. First prove the theorem for non-negative functions, then extend to all functions as you've indicated.

For nonnegative $f$, note that if $h$ is bounded and has finite support on $A$, then you can define $$h_E(x) =\begin{cases} h(x) & x\in A\\0 & x \in E \setminus A\end{cases}$$
Then $h_E$ is bounded and has finite support on $E$. Further, $h_E\chi_A = h_E$ and $h_E|_A = h$. Conversely if $h$ is bounded and has finite support on $E$, then $h\chi_A|_A$ is bounded and has finite support on $A$.

**Edit:** as requested, where I've tried to dot all the i's and cross all the t's.

For notational convenience, for measurable sets $B$ and measurable non-negative functions $g$, define ${\scr M}(g, B)$ to be the set of all bounded measurable functions $h$ of finite support on $B$ such that $0 \le h \le g$.

Let $f$ be a non-negative measurable function on $E$ and $A$ a measurable subset of $E$. Then $\chi_Af$ is also a measurable function on $E$.

Now if $h \in {\scr M}(\chi_Af,E)$ and $x \in E \setminus A$, then $0 \le h(x) \le \chi_A(x)f(x) = 0\cdot f(x) = 0$. Hence $\operatorname{supt} h \subseteq A$. And for $x \in A$, $0 \le h(x) \le \chi_A(x)f(x) = 1\cdot f(x) = f(x)$, so $0 \le h \le f$ on $A$. Therefore $h|_A \in {\scr M}(f,A)$. And, $$\int_E h = \int_A h + \int_{E\setminus A} h = \int_A h$$ since $h = 0$ on $E\setminus A$.

Conversely, if $h' \in {\scr M}(f,A)$, then define $h : E \to \bar{\Bbb R}$ by $$h(x) = \begin{cases} h'(x) & x \in A\\0 & x \notin A\end{cases}$$
Then $h$ is measurable, $\operatorname{supt} h = \operatorname{supt} h'$ and therefore is finite, and if $h' < M$, then $M > 0$, so $h < M$ as well. And lastly  $$h(x) = \begin{cases} h'(x) \le f(x) = \chi_A(x)f(x) & x \in A\\0 = \chi_A(x)f(x) & x \notin A\end{cases}$$
Hence $h \in {\scr M}(\chi_Af,E), h' = h|_A$ and therefore $$\int_E h = \int_A h'.$$ Therefore the restriction map $T\ :\ {\scr M}(\chi_Af,E) \to {\scr M}(f,A)\ :\ h \to h_A$ is a bijection, and $\int_E h = \int_A T(h)$. So $$\begin{align}\int \chi_Af &= \sup\left\{\int_E h \ :\ h \in {\scr M}(\chi_Af,E)\right\}\\
&=\sup\left\{\int_A T(h) \ :\ h \in {\scr M}(\chi_Af,E)\right\}\\
&=\sup\left\{\int_A T(h) \ :\ T(h) \in {\scr M}(f,A)\right\}\\
&=\sup\left\{\int_A h' \ :\ h' \in {\scr M}(f,A)\right\}\\
&=\int_A f\end{align}$$

When $f$ may be negative, $$\int_E\chi_Af = \int_E\chi_Af^+ -\int_E\chi_Af^- = \int_A f^+ - \int_Af^- = \int_Af$$

Comment: if you add more details to this answer, I will award you the bounty. It's an excellent solution, but I want to see more.

Comment: @JessyCat - see the edit.